# codeigniter active record, get where array of values

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord, where-clause

I need get row where id in array.

for example,

```
$array = (1,2,67,102,178,678);
```

after query I need rows where id=1,id=2,id=67,id=102,id=178,id=678

and i want update records this way

Comment: Use `$this->db->where_in()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `where_in`:

```
$this->db->where_in('id', $array);
```

To retrieve the records use:

```
$this->db->get('table_name')->result();
```

To update the records use:

```
$this->db->update('table_name');
```